# SQL 2005 cluster to use local storage for backups?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005, storage, cluster

I've built an active/active SQL 2005 cluster using LUNs for SQL, Data, and Logs.

Unfortunately, I tried to use local storage (both machines have a local B:) for backups - hey, shared storage is expensive and this is only a temporary location that awaits another routine that moves the SQL backups to tape.

Anyway, SQL doesn't seem to like the local B: in the cluster.

Is there any way to use the local drives?  UNC paths?

I'm afraid that it is obvious that I'm new at this - please educate me.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm confused.  It seems that the local B: is working after all - the DBA says it was failing before due to an integrity check.  So are local drives available or not?

I tried to access the UNC path first, but that definitely failed.  Typing in B:... seems to be working, you just can't browse to it.

So I'm not sure how to resolve that experience with the experience of Massimo that I marked below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clustered installation of SQL Server will only be able to directly access clustered disks; there's no workaround for that.

You can backup to a network location, of course.

Comment: In order do backup to a network location, the user account SQL Server uses to run needs to have access to the network share; so, if your SQL Server instance is running as "DOMAIN\sql.server", you need to give that user write access to the location you're saving your backups to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the network share.

What about the seemingly working local drive - do you expect that this will fail in some fashion under certain conditions?  Thanks

Comment: It could work (as long as you have a B: drive on both nodes), but I'm quite sure it's not supported.

Comment: I'm quite sure it *would* be supported, if the same drive letter exists on each node.  Not all resources accessed by a clustered instance need to be clustered.